# How to avoid old files on scratch directory getting deleted?

Tags: linux, shell, touch

In our supercomputer center system automatically delete files older than 30 days on the scratch directory. Is there any way to avoid this?
May be a shell script to crawl all files in the folder and update their last modified time with touch command.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Ask your sysadmin.

Comment: A permanent solution would be like how @IporSircer suggested, talk to your sysadmin. For a temporary solution though, what you said should work. Create a `cron` job to run once every 30 days to `touch` all the files in your "scratch" folder.